# How does PHP make money? They don't solicit donations and they don't sell pro solutions

Tags: php, zend-studio

I was just wondering: PHP is such a good robust thing for make quick web applications but they don't have a donation box , neither are they selling shirts or mugs etc. They also don't have a "pro" solution to be bought and use so how do their developers get paid? I know it's open source and a lot of intelligent are behind it contributing to it but someone must be there to check and balance and paying the hosting etc. This open source organization is a bit different than others: some have hosting plans , paid tutorials etc. I only find Zend doing selling and I don't know if zend is the company behind PHP or is PHP behind Zend ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zend (the company behind PHP) engages in several commercial activities:

Software sales: Zend Studio, Zend Server

Training: Zend Certification, Zend Framework Certification

Consultation, and more. See [zend.com](http://zend.com) for details.

Comment: Surely they have spent alot of money on PHP. But how do they actually **make** money with PHP? Is it simply by"brand boosting" / "marketing"?

Comment: @Pacerier As far as I can tell, Zend makes no money from PHP directly. However, as I explained in my answer, they make their money by producing products that support the PHP industry.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the answer: http://shop.zend.com/en/